Apache Jackrabbit Oak 1.68 with MongoDB 5.0 incompatiblity
I am trying to configure apache oak with mongo db. I am using newest dependencies:

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
        <artifactId>oak-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.68.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
        <artifactId>oak-jcr</artifactId>
        <version>1.68.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
        <artifactId>oak-store-document</artifactId>
        <version>1.68.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.4</version>
    </dependency>

According to official documentation https://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/nodestore/document/mongo-document-store.html I should use MongoDB 5.0 version. The problem is that the example code that is on the official documentation page that initializes DocumentNodeStore uses com.mongodb.MongoClient which is available in 3.x mongodb driver


    DocumentNodeStore store = new MongoDocumentNodeStoreBuilder()
        .setMongoDB("mongodb://localhost:27017", "oak", 0).build();


After downgrading the driver to 3.12.14 I get different error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.operation.ReadOperation
Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

I managed to make it work using mongo-java-driver 3.12.14

I can confirm that me too using mongo-java-driver 3.12.14 and it works
